# Bash code to check for SSH/Samba connections?

Tags: bash

I currently use the following cron job to put the computer in suspend mode and wake it up the following day:

```
0 13 * * * /usr/sbin/rtcwake -m standby -u -t $(date +\%s -d 'tomorrow 1145')
```

I'd like to replace this with a call to a Bash script that will
be called every hour…

```
check if anyone is currently connected through SSH or Samba (backup job)
If no one is connected, go into suspend mode
else try again the next hour.
```

Does someone have some working code I could use?

Thank you.

Comment: You can use `ps ax | grep sshd` to show ssh connections, and `smbstatus` to show the samba. The rest of is only some fluff...

Answer (score 0):

`w`:

> Show who is logged on and what they are doing.